# How to skip before filters for json/xml requests in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, before-filter

I found a way to skip before filters based on the format, as seen below, but I'm wondering if there is a better way since this clutters things and isn't very DRY.

```
before_filter do |controller|
  :current_cart unless controller.request.format.js?
end
```

If I don't do this, json requests fail because the current_cart method, and other methods, do things only meant for html.

Comment: This only works in Rails 4+ if you change `:current_cart` to a direct call to the method: `current_cart`. The block syntax is preferable in some cases, so I thought I'd point out how to use your example correctly.

Answer (score 23):

You could do it this way:

```
before_filter :current_cart, :unless => :format_js?

def format_js?
  request.format.js?
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really helpful! I think `format_json?` is a better name for the method though.

Comment: I changed it to `format_js` I agree the other name was not as good but js != json. Thanks for the thought!